# Convert Base64 to PNG-File and save on Ktor Backende

Tags: kotlin, base64, save, png, ktor

I need to save an image from the Client App as PNG on the Backend.
Im sending the Image as Base64 with Post to the Backend.
I cant find a way to convert the Base64 String  to an PNG File and dont know, how I could save them as File on the Server.

Thats the function I use to get the Data from the client. In val picture I get the Image as Base64.

```
fun savepicture(data: getpicture) =
        transaction {
            val userid= data.userid
            val date = data.date 
            val time = data.time 
            val picture= data.picture
            println("$picture")

            try {
                decodeImage(aufnahme)
            }
            catch(e: Exception) {
                println("Fehler: $e")
            }

            if (picture.isNotEmpty()) {
                return@transaction true
            }
            return@transaction  false
        }
```

```
fun decodeImage(image: String) {

        val pictureBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(image)
        val path = Path("Path/to/destination")
        path.writeBytes(pictureBytes)
    }
```

With this function i create the Base64 String. The Bitmap is created of a picture taken form the Device.

```
fun encodeImage(bm: Bitmap): String? {
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, baos)
        val b = baos.toByteArray()
        return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b)
    }
```

I hope someone could help me to convert and save my image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Note that you're encoding twice your initial image. You should only use the encoder once. Why do you use both `encode()` and `encodeToString()`?

Comment: I thought i need t use both, i cleared them now. At the Moment i get a image.png File on the Folder but i cant open it as PNG. The content of the File is the Base64 code. When i use the Code with a translator i get the Picture. Do i need to transform the bytearray to an PNG File before i safe it?

Comment: Thanks for the help, finaly i found a failure in the formatation of the Base64 Format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Base64` to decode your base64 string into bytes. Then you'll need to write the bytes into a file.

For instance:

```kotlin
val picture: String = "the base64 data here as a string"

// decode the base64 text into bytes
val pictureBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(picture)

// write the bytes to a file
val path = Path("the/path/to/the/file.png")
path.writeBytes(pictureBytes)
```

Comment: When i use this Code i get the error message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a, is it a problem with decoding? i edited the Question with the function to create the Base64 String.